# Web Service Call Stopped Processing

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I have a bunch of Xamarin iOS applications running on our Corporate iPhones and iPads.  I recently upgraded my Visual Studio and Mac Book Pro to latest release version and my applications are no longer PROCESSING data from my web service correctly.  I did not change version of Xamarin.Forms

VS 2017 Version 15.9.13
Xamarin.Forms.2.4.0.282

1. The web services are http.  I have my NSAppTransportSecurityNSAllowsArbitraryLoads

   set to allow http.
2. I am using the flag true to generate the Task.Factory.FromAsync methods in the Web Service Reference.cs file.
3. I could go on with describing how everything works if anyone needs more info.

Luckily, my Mac Book Pro Simulator has old and new versions of my apps installed in different iPhone/iPad devices for me to test.  I installed fiddler to make sure all the requests/responses were the same.  My old App in one device works and my new App in a different device fails.  Same thing for ALL of my Applications.  Old one works and new one fails.

When I review fiddler, the requests and responses are all working the same:
    Request is made
    App gets an authentication prompt
    Authentication happens
    Request returns code 200 with the data requested

The only difference in Fiddler is that two of the headers are in a different order:  Working one has SOAPAction first and Content-Type next, the one failing has Content-Type and then SOAPAction.  I am grasping at straws here because the order of these headers should not matter.

This is for all the applications.  The only problem is that my new applications are ignoring the response.  It is almost like the endMethod function from the parameter passed to FromAsync is never called.

This is the function call:

```
    public async Task<ProcessLogon> ExecuteSaveLogon(DeviceItem DeviceItem)
    {
        ResultLogin = new ProcessLogon();

        try
        {
            var ProcessLogon = await Task<WebServiceTrading.ProcessLogon>.Factory.FromAsync(serviceTrading.BeginSaveLogon, serviceTrading.EndSaveLogon, ToServiceTrading(DeviceItem), TaskCreationOptions.None);

            ResultLogin = FromServiceTrading(ProcessLogon);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(@"ExecuteSaveLogon ERROR {0}", ex.Message);
        }

        return ResultLogin;
    }
```

Does anyone know of any DEBUG or LOGGING tools that I could use to find out why my successful response is lost?

Comment: Xamarin.Forms.2.4.0.282 is a very old version why not try the latest one? I noticed you used `Task.Factory.FromAsync()` to call your web service, why not try HttpClient's `PostAsync` directly? The order of header's parameters should not affect the result. Can you please test another simple rest api?

Comment: This is too funny.  My Macbook Pro was too old to upgrade so we bought a new one.  Installed latest of everything on the Macbook, installed VS 2019 and created a new mobile project.  Moved all my code over to the new solution and the SAME EXACT BEHAVIOR is happening.  Fiddler shows the successful response but my EndMethod is never called.  I tried a bunch of different web methods and none of them work.